# bootstrap mixed horizontal and inline content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble getting the Bootstrap FORM elements to work/display as I want.

I read here on how to nest the form-group inside of form-inline  (inside yet another parent form-group)

Which gets me 'somewhat' inline content.. but the spacing and stuff is off.

I'm new to this 'Bootstrap' style of grid/layout.. so it may be something obvious or stupidly overlooked.

[image: inline content no space]

Here is my code to get the above:

```
<!-- Organization -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputOrganization" class="col-sm-12">Organization <span style="font-size:11px;">(labels on top/full width)</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputOrganization" placeholder="Organization" name="organization">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Contact Person -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputContactPerson" class="col-sm-12">Contact Person <span style="font-size:11px;">(labels on top/full width)</span></label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputContactPerson" placeholder="ContactPerson" name="contactperson">
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">              
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="inputCity">City</label><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="inputCity" placeholder="City" name="city" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label for="inputState">State</label><br>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="inputState" placeholder="State" name="state" style="width:100%;">
                    </div>                      
                </div>                          
            </div>
```

My/the problem is.. that I can NOT figure out to get the the following:

- City & State 'labels' on top of fields
- City & State fields have a 'space' between them (not butted up against each other like in the image)
- City & State fields should each be 50% width.. so that the City field STARTS where all other fields start..  and State field ENDS where all other fields end   *(in the image shown.. there no space between the inline fields and State field does NOT stretch to end where the above Contact Person field ends)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Bootstrap version?

Comment: Sorry about that!  I believe it is 3.2

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/kaf1tj4w/1/

Comment: So all you did was remove the "col-sm-12" in the "form-inline" parent container?  Is that it?

Comment: And also reduced the margin-bottom to 2 pixels for all labels :)

Comment: Still your html seems odd...